# Background process is waiting and not continuing process

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, background-process

I have a program that has to call the sqlmap API and run it in the background, if you've ever used sqlmap you would know that the sqlmap API process starts and continues running until exited. It appears that the program is waiting for sqlmap's API to stop running before continuing the process:

Output:

```
[11:02:10 INFO] creating arguments for sqlmap...
[11:02:10 INFO] attempting to find sqlmap on your system...
[11:02:10 INFO] attempting to call sqlmap API...
------------------------------
[11:02:12] [INFO] Running REST-JSON API server at '127.0.0.1:8775'..
[11:02:12] [INFO] Admin ID: 7e8f2de3647ff14d8cd777f3fddabca8
[11:02:12] [DEBUG] IPC database: '/tmp/sqlmapipc-mH6At_'
[11:02:12] [DEBUG] REST-JSON API server connected to IPC database
[11:02:13] [DEBUG] Using adapter 'wsgiref' to run bottle
# just hangs here
```

Code:

```
try:
    path = find_sqlmap("sqlmap", verbose=verbose)
    lib.core.settings.logger.info(lib.core.settings.set_color(
        "attempting to call sqlmap API..."
    ))
    called = subprocess.Popen(
        "python {}/sqlmapapi.py -s".format("".join(path)),
        shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        close_fds=True
    )
    print("-" * 30)
    for line in iter(called.stdout.readline, ""):
        print(line.strip())
    print("-" * 30)
    lib.core.settings.logger.info(lib.core.settings.set_color(
        "API started with PID {}, continuing process...".format(
            called.pid
        )
    ))
except Exception as e:
    lib.core.settings.logger.exception("test")
    print e
    lib.core.settings.logger.error(lib.core.settings.set_color(
        "ran into an error while trying to start the sqlmap API, please do it manually...", level=50
    ))
```

As you can see it will start the API, but then it will just hang at that point and will not continue (I've let it sit for about five minutes). So my question being, is there a way I can fork the system call into the background and continue moving along? I've been under the impression the `subprocess.Popen` will create a background process, that does not appear to be the truth here though. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It *is* running in the background; the problem is that you keep trying to read from its standard output, which will stay open as long as it *continues* to run in the background.

Comment: Don't use `shell=True` here; use `Popen(["python", os.path.join("".join(path), "sqlmapapi.py"), "-s"], stdout=..., stderr=..., close_fds=True)`.

Comment: @chepner So let me see if I understand you correctly, stop reading from the output, and get rido of `shell=True`?